# How to loop and build a collection, the scala way

Tags: scala

I want to build a list using a block. This is something that I would do in ruby, but I don't feel like it's the best way to do it in scala:

```
var list = List[A]()
myMetod { a =>
  list ::= a
}
list
```

How could I do this better?

Comment: Your code does not really show what a=> is (i did not downvote) but could be more clear.

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing that what you are after is simply

```
val list = {
  ...
  <some expression yielding the list>
}
```

That is, the block can be a sequence of statements that ultimately yields the `List[A]` you want bound to symbol `list`.